# What's wrong with the for loops in this code?

Tags: c, string, for-loop, vector, flags

Im reading the book *The C Programming Language*, and I cant figure out what is wrong with my code in this exercise.

The exercise asks for you to implement a version of the `squeeze()` function that deletes each character in s1 that matches with any character in the string s2.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char s1[100];
    char s2[100];
    int c;
    int i;
    int j;
    int flag=0;
    char s3[100];

    printf("TYPE THE FIRST STRING\n");
    for(i=0;s1[i-1]!='\n';i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &s1[i]);
    }


    printf("\n\nTYPE THE SECOND STRING\n");
    for(i=0;s2[i-1]!='\n';i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &s2[i]);
    }


    for(i=0;s1[i]!='\n';i++)/*sets the "i" character of s1 to be compared*/
    {
        for(j=0;s2[j]!='\n';j++)/*compares the "i" character in s1 with
        {                         every character on s2*/
            if(s1[i]==s2[j])
            {
                flag=1;/*sets the flag variable to one if it finds 2 equal 
                break;   characters and stops the loop*/
            }
        }
        if(flag!=1)/*if it have not found a matching pair of chacters,
        {            this part copies the s1 char to s3*/
            s3[i]=s1[i];
        }
        flag=0;
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n%s",s3);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that if I input "**test**" in s1 and "**second**" in s2, it only prints "**t**". It stops as soon it finds a matching pair. The `flag` is not properly working ? I'm 2 hours+ in this exercise and cannot solve it.

Comment: `s1` is not initialized so this `for(i=0;s1[i-1]!='\n';i++)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Also your `break;` is inside the comment (line after `flag = 1;`).

Comment: Your first loop and second loop are wrong. If you begin i from 0, s1[-1] and [s2-1] are not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; s1[i-1] != '\n'; i++)
```

The predicate on the first iteration of this loop will access `s1[-1]`, which is out of bounds, and in turn invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). The loop involving `s2` has the same issue.

Additionally, your strings are never NUL terminated, and their buffers are vulnerable to overflowing via `scanf`.

You have multiple instances of `/* */` comments spanning multiple lines, which is commenting out sections of your code: two opening `{`, and the `break`.

Even after fixing the issue with the comments

```
if (flag != 1) {
    s3[i] = s1[i];
}
```

is going to leave holes in your final string. You'll need a separate index counter for `s3` that only increases as the string grows in length.

A quick example where we initialize our buffers (in particular this NUL terminates `s3`), and use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to limit our input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char s1[100] = { 0 },
         s2[100] = { 0 },
         s3[100] = { 0 };
    int flag = 0;
    size_t k = 0;

    if (
        !fgets(s1, sizeof s1, stdin) ||
        !fgets(s2, sizeof s2, stdin)
    ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read input.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; s1[i] && s1[i] != '\n'; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; s2[j] && s2[j] != '\n'; j++) {
            if (s1[i] == s2[j]) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0)
            s3[k++] = s1[i];
        flag = 0;
    }

    printf("%s\n", s3);
}
```

---

Alternatively, using [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr), we can compose a tidy function:

```
#include <string.h>

void squeeze(char *dest, const char *source, const char *filter) {
    for (; *source; source++)
        if (!strchr(filter, *source))
            *dest++ = *source;

    *dest = '\0';
}
```